# How to write query where string contains any data from array using WHERE IN()?

Tags: mysql, sql

If I have table like this

```
+------+---------------------------+
|  Id  |  City                     |
+------+---------------------------+
|   1  | Vancouver, Miami, New York| 
+------+---------------------------+
|   2  | Vancouver Miami           | 
+------+---------------------------+
|   3  | New York                  | 
+------+---------------------------+
|   4  | Miami                     | 
+------+---------------------------+
|   5  | Vancouver, New York       | 
+------+---------------------------+
|   6  | New York Miami            | 
+------+---------------------------+
|   7  | Vancouver                 | 
+------+---------------------------+
```

And some user want get data from Miami or Vancouver

How to write query to get data with id 1,2,4,5,6,7

Data with id 3 should not be displayed because there is no Miami or Vancouver in that string

**EDIT:** Because I am getting Miami and Vancouver in array list I need query using function WHERE IN ()

Comment: You cannot use in operator because your data is not normalised.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways of doing this, both of them don't involve using `WHERE IN` approach, it's not possible to use wild card matching on multiple values with `IN` operator.

1. Use `OR` statement

   `SELECT * FROM yourtable WHERE CITY LIKE '%Miami%' OR CITY LIKE '%Vancouver%'`
2. Using `REGEXP` for Mysql5.0 and above

   `SELECT * FROM yourtable WHERE CITY REGEXP 'Miami|Vancouver'`

Comment: I just edited my question, sorry for lack of information

Comment: What if the city is called `York`, not `New York`?

Comment: Thanks a lot, that helped